# Appending ID column back into sampled image

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sample

With a lot of help I recently figured out how to extract NDVI values for a specific date for a collection of GPS points ([Extracting NDVI value for GPS points - how can I extract NDVI value for specific date and time for each GPS point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/403828/188402))

However, when sampling the image to extract the NDVI value I lose my ID column - so I do not know for which GPS point I have just extracted the NDVI value.

After a suggestion I tried using:

```
 var extract = filtIm.sampleRegions({
    collection: pts,
    properties: ['OBJECTID'],
    scale: 30
  });
```

but in my final feature collection, the 'ObjectID' column still does not pop up.Is there a way in which I could append my NDVI value back into the original GPS point feature collection?

My full code:

```
/////////////////////////////
//// Obtain NDVI layer //////
/////////////////////////////
var filtered = L8.filterDate('2017-01-01', '2021-06-01').filterBounds(pts);
var rgb_vis = {min:0, max: 0.3, bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2']};
var image = ee.Image(filtered.first());

function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']);
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}
var NDVI = addNDVI(image);
var with_ndvi = filtered.map(addNDVI);
Map.addLayer(filtered, rgb_vis, 'RGB');
Map.addLayer(NDVI, {bands: 'nd', min:0, max:1}, 'NDVI');
Map.addLayer(with_ndvi, {bands: 'nd', min:0, max:1}, 'withNDVI');

/////////////////////// EXTRACT NDVI /////////
// Use the pts date field to filter the image collection
// and then extract the image values of the filtered image
var extractpts = pts.map(function(feat){
  // Get date from each pts feature
  var date = feat.get('Fixtime');
  // Convert it to date format, indicating the format
   date = ee.Date.parse('d/M/y H:m', date);
  
  // Create range to filter image, e.g, one week before or after
  var start = date.advance(-1, 'month');
  var end = date.advance(1, 'month');
  
  // Filter using the date ranges and get first image
  var filtIm = with_ndvi.filterDate(start, end)
                       .first();

  // Sample image info using the feature                     
  var extract = filtIm.sampleRegions({
    collection: pts,
    properties: ['OBJECTID'],
    scale: 30
  });
  
  return extract;
});

// Flatten FeatureCollections into a single FeatureCollection
extractpts = extractpts.flatten();
print(extractpts.first());
```

Due to the sensitive nature of my GPS dataset I can only provide a subset:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/u17177121/LIW_Subset

Comment: I ran the entire code and the 'OBJECTID' property is in the final `extractpts` object. Try running this line at the end of your code to verify it: `print(extractpts.select(['OBJECTID', 'nd']));`

Comment: For some reason it is still not showing up in mine. If I used my condensed data set that I made public there is no problem, but the extended one does not produce an OJBECTID property even though it has the exact same set up.

Comment: Problem solved by uploading the same file again - not sure what went wrong with the original file. Thank you for your help!